# How can user 1 or super admin be excluded in search results in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm looking for a way to exclude the admin user or user 1 from user search results in drupal 7.

I want this to not show up for security reasons.

Comment: In addition to my answer, are you intending on hiding content created by the admin from search results too and/or removing the created by admin line on results as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you build a custom search using Views, you can set the filter(s) to only show users with certain roles.  Do not expose the filter to users.  If User 1 has the "administrator" role and everyone else has another (non-administrator) role, when you apply the filter, only non-administrator accounts will show up when a search is run.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [hook_preprocess_search_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) by inserting the following into template.php. Note you'll have to clear the Drupal cache to enable this function in Configuration -> Performance -> Clear Cache

```
function <themename>_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  global $language;

  $display_result = true;

  if( $variables['module'] == 'user' ) {
    if( $variables['user']->uid == 1 || $variables['id'] == 1 ) {
      $display_result = false;
      $variables = array();
    }
  }

  if( $display_result ) {
      $result = $variables['result'];
      $variables['url'] = check_url($result['link']);
      $variables['title'] = check_plain($result['title']);
      if (isset($result['language']) && $result['language'] != $language->language && $result['language'] != LANGUAGE_NONE) {
        $variables['title_attributes_array']['xml:lang'] = $result['language'];
        $variables['content_attributes_array']['xml:lang'] = $result['language'];
      }

      $info = array();
      if (!empty($result['module'])) {
        $info['module'] = check_plain($result['module']);
      }
      if (!empty($result['user'])) {
        $info['user'] = $result['user'];
      }
      if (!empty($result['date'])) {
        $info['date'] = format_date($result['date'], 'short');
      }
      if (isset($result['extra']) && is_array($result['extra'])) {
        $info = array_merge($info, $result['extra']);
      }
      // Check for existence. User search does not include snippets.
      $variables['snippet'] = isset($result['snippet']) ? $result['snippet'] : '';
      // Provide separated and grouped meta information..
      $variables['info_split'] = $info;
      $variables['info'] = implode(' - ', $info);
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'search_result__' . $variables['module'];
  }
}
```

Another way to do it would be [search-result.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search-result.tpl.php/7) and check the `$info_split` array to check if the search result was user one and not display any output.

Don't forget that you'll need to also prevent users from visiting site.com/user/1 as they'll be able to get just as much information from this page.